# Why does Typescript arrow function property has access to this

Tags: javascript, typescript, binding, arrow-functions

I am trying to understand the scope of arrow functions. I implemented a small program in Angular, but I got confused a bit. In the code below I don't really understand why this binds to the `TestComponent`

```
export class TestComponent {
 a: string = "Hello World";
 myArrowFunction = () => {
  console.log(this.a); //
 }
 constructor(){
  myArrowFunction(); //output: "Hello World"
 }
}
```

Arrow functions don't have its own `this`, so the `this` binds to the parent, is that right? `myArrowFunction` belongs to `TestComponent`, so `this` in `myArrowFunction` should be undefined, but in the example above `this` binds to `TestComponent` why?

```
    test = {
        b: "Hello World",
        foo: () => {
            console.log(this.b);
        }
    }
        
    test.foo(); //output: undefined
```

Where is the difference to the javascript code above? There this.b is undefined.

Comment: Some useful refs: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). [Medium Post](https://medium.com/@iampika/es6-arrow-functions-syntax-and-lexical-scoping-d061732071e7)

Comment: `this.myArrowFunction = () => {...}` is assigned inside the `constructor()`

Comment: What do you mean by assigned?

Comment: `test = { b: "Hello World", foo: () => { console.log(this.b); } }
  test.foo();`
Isn't this the same?

Comment: @YusufIpek I mean you take a property or a variable and assign it a new value. In this case this value is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, because of the arrow function this refers to the upper object so your instance.

```js
//console.log(this)
class TestComponent {
    myArrowFunction = () => {// function set in instance
        console.log(this); //
    }
    myFunction() {// function set in prototype
        console.log(this); //
    }
    constructor() {
        this.a = "Hello World";
        this.myArrowFunction(); //output: "Hello World"
    }
}

function A() {
    this.foo = () => { console.log(this) };// A instance
    this.foo()
}
A.prototype.bar = () => { console.log(this) };// global
new A();
//const a = new TestComponent();
```

Comment: Why is the upper object TestComponent?

Comment: because look at the equivalence with prototype notation in my example

Comment: I understand your example, however what about Objects created with {}, like my second code example in the description? Could you please explain me that?

Comment: in your last example with {} there is no function scope so this is the global variable (could you accept the answser)

Comment: One last question. But if I would replace the arrow function in the example with a regular function, then access to this.b would work, what is the reason for that?

Comment: because arrow function has no function scope behavior, function does.